# Setting struct equal to the contents from a pointer to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is how I have declared my structs and the one pointer to the struct.

```
    struct com rt, cur;
    struct com *hold;
```

I save the contents of rt into cur. As cur is going to be edited after in a different function. I then want to get the contents from the pointer `hold` and save them into `rt`. This is where I have `*rt = hold;` but it throws and error `error: invalid type argument of unary '*' (have 'struct com')`

```
        cur = rt;
        hold =&cur;

        //call function to edit cur

        *rt = hold;
```

I'm unsure what the last line should be.

Comment: RT is not of pointer type, it is a regular struct com. there fore you cannot dereference it with the asterisk.

Comment: @scerrecrow but I want to get the contents that `hold` is pointing to and set them to `rt`

Comment: `rt=*hold`, but you can ptobably ditch `hold` altogether and use `&cur` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*hold` is pointer and `hold` is address of pointer.Now `*rt` is pointer and what you are doing is pointer =address that is wrong.

> Setting struct equal to the contents from a pointer to struct

to get the contents from a (pointer to struct) we need to deference (pointer to struct).In this case `hold` is your (pointer to struct) so deference it means `*hold`

> I then want to get the contents from the pointer hold and save them
>   into rt

`rt = *hold`

Answer (score 1):

**I then want to get the contents from the pointer `hold` and save them into `rt`**

To do this, try

```
cur = rt;
hold =&cur;

//call function to edit cur

rt = *hold;
```

---

`hold` is a pointer, and to get the structure content to which it is pointing, you need to dereference the pointer, meaning `*hold`.

Now, that structure content you want to store in `rt`, So just use `rt`, as it is just a normal variable.